# Can I still sign apps with my certificates after my Apple Developer Program membership expires?

Tags: macos, app-store, signature

I have an OSX app distributed through my website and not published to the Apple store.
I enrolled to the Apple developer program to get a signing certificate and sign my app.

Do I need to renew my membership to continue to sign my app?
Do the app signature will remains trusted by OS X?

Comment: Recall that on Feb 14 a certificate used to sign apps on the Mac App Store was replaced because the certificate had expired.